# Running 'swift build' crashes with segmentation fault when dependency name equals project's name

Tags: swift, crash, segmentation-fault, swift-package-manager

Example:

```
> mkdir myProject && cd myProject
> swift package init --type executable
```

Edit `Package.swift` (added 1 dependency):

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "myProject",
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on. 
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/someone/myProject.git", from: "1.0.0"),
    ],  
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on. 
        .target(
            name: "myProject",
            dependencies: []),
    ]   
)
```

Build it:

```
> swift build
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Environment**

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Swift version 4.1-dev (LLVM 260a172ffb, Clang cd84be6c42, Swift 05b1b2be7c)

Is anyone aware if this was recently introduced and/or is happening with other versions of swift?

Comment: I wanted to test this repo: https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git, so I created a dummy project called "vapor" to test it, and to my surprise, it crashed.

Comment: You should report the lack of error message to the Swift tools team, not to the crowd on SO.  I hope you realize that a recursive dependency is a user error.

Comment: Thanks Avi, I did report it, yesterday. I was asking if other(s) had had this issue in other versions of swift. Keep in mind that something like this should not cause segmentation fault, but gracefully handle it.

Comment: Have you tried the 4.2 snapshots?  The 4.1 release was a mess of crash bugs in the compiler, and presumably, other parts of the toolchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug:

**Swift Bug SR-7597**

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7597